# How to encode a Cisco Type 8 secret without a cisco device using python

Tags: encryption, sha256, password-encryption, cisco

I was wondering if it is possible to generate the hashed secret shown in the CISCO documentation using a python script, without a CISCO device.

https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/article/cisco-routers-password-types

```
Example :

R1(config)# username yasser algorithm-type sha256 secret cisco

R1# show running-config | inc username

username yasser secret 8 $8$dsYGNam3K1SIJO$7nv/35M/qr6t.dVc7UY9zrJDWRVqncHub1PE9UlMQFs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash values from the linked example can be reproduced if the following is considered in addition to the information given there:

- the format is `$8$<random 14 bytes salt>$<Base64 encoded PBKDF2 hash>`
- 20000 as iteration count for PBKDF2
- `./0-9A-Za-z` as Base64 alphabet
- no Base64 padding

While the iteration count is described [here](https://media.defense.gov/2022/Feb/17/2002940795/-1/-1/1/CSI_CISCO_PASSWORD_TYPES_BEST_PRACTICES_20220217.PDF), the others are more or less educated guesses (e.g. `./0-9A-Za-z` is a common variant with the letter `.`), which are eventually confirmed by the successful tests.

A possible Python implementation is:

```py
import hashlib
import base64

STD_B64_ALPHABET   = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
CISCO_B64_ALPHABET = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
TRANS = str.maketrans(STD_B64_ALPHABET, CISCO_B64_ALPHABET)

def b64CiscoEncode(data):
    return base64.b64encode(data).decode('ascii').translate(TRANS).rstrip('=')

def type8Hash(salt, password):   
    return b64CiscoEncode(hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 20000))

# $8$mTj4RZG8N9ZDOk$elY/asfm8kD3iDmkBe3hD2r4xcA/0oWS5V3os.O91u.
print(type8Hash(b'mTj4RZG8N9ZDOk', b'cisco')) # elY/asfm8kD3iDmkBe3hD2r4xcA/0oWS5V3os.O91u.

# $8$dsYGNam3K1SIJO$7nv/35M/qr6t.dVc7UY9zrJDWRVqncHub1PE9UlMQFs
print(type8Hash(b'dsYGNam3K1SIJO', b'cisco')) # 7nv/35M/qr6t.dVc7UY9zrJDWRVqncHub1PE9UlMQFs
```

which successfully reproduces the hashes from the linked example.

---

**Edit:**

Concerning your comment: The salt is produced by randomly generating 10 bytes (= 80 bits) that are Base64 encoded (using the Cisco alphabet), resulting in 14 bytes. The type 8 hashed password is the concatenation of 8-prefix, salt and Base64 encoded PBKDF2 hash:

```php
import hashlib
import base64
import os

salt = b64CiscoEncode(os.urandom(10)) # create random 10 bytes (=80 bits) salt and Base64 encode
password = b'cisco'
hash = type8Hash(salt.encode('ascii'), password) # calculate Base64 encoded PBKDF2 hash 

print("$8$%s$%s" %(salt, hash)) # concatenate 8 prefix, salt and Base64 encoded PBKDF2 hash
```

If the hash is to be reconstructed to an existing type 8 hashed password, simply use the corresponding salt instead of the freshly generated salt (as in the first part of the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the response Topaco, this script is generating these 2 hashes

elY/asfm8kD3iDmkBe3hD2r4xcA/0oWS5V3os.O91u.
7nv/35M/qr6t.dVc7UY9zrJDWRVqncHub1PE9UlMQFs


I was more interested in the type8 hashed pwds, something like this

$8$mTj4RZG8N9ZDOk$elY/asfm8kD3iDmkBe3hD2r4xcA/0oWS5V3os.O91u.
$8$dsYGNam3K1SIJO$7nv/35M/qr6t.dVc7UY9zrJDWRVqncHub1PE9UlMQFs

Comment: @EduardoAEDUARDOFernandezDi - That's just the concatenation of 8-prefix, salt and hash, see the edit section of my answer. Or are you asking how to create the random salt?

Comment: @EduardoAEDUARDOFernandezDi - I've augmented my answer with the generation of the salt and the concatenation of prefix, salt and hash.

Comment: Your implementation has the same length as this other one, but for some reason, these type8 pwds are not working for my CISCO lab :)

https://github.com/BrettVerney/ciscoPWDhasher/blob/master/CiscoPWDhasher/__init__.py

Comment: When I add a pwd through CLI the running config is actually showing a smaller hashed pwd

$8$5sjfCarEflX6e5FXVMLAulwwPlYXVaxA0Pu2itS0eWE=

Comment: @EduardoAEDUARDOFernandezDi - I don't see any difference between the code I posted and the code you linked (`type8(pwd)` - method). Both conform to the [specification](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/article/cisco-routers-password-types) you linked, as opposed to the value you posted in your last comment.

Comment: @EduardoAEDUARDOFernandezDi - A possible explanation would be that in the short type8 hash, for some reason, no salt is used, so the second part is missing. This is purely guessed, though. It is also irritating that the Base64 padding is present (in contrast to the posted specification), which also indicates a different Base64 padding. Can you post sample data, i.e. a test password and the short type8 hash generated from it?

Comment: test pwd cisco

$8$mTj4RZG8N9ZDOk$elY/asfm8kD3iDmkBe3hD2r4xcA/0oWS5V3os.O91u.

Comment: @EduardoAEDUARDOFernandezDi - No, this is one of the type 8 hashes that can be reproduced by my code, see the first example in the first code snippet of my answer. You posted a **short** type 8 hash that differs from the specification. From such an example complette data i.e. type 8 hash **and** password would be interesting.

Comment: Its producing this hash for pwd = cisco
$8$5sjfCarEflX6e5FXVMLAulwwPlYXVaxA0Pu2itS0eWE=

Comment: @EduardoAEDUARDOFernandezDi - I cannot reproduce this hash with an empty salt (neither with the modified nor the standard Base64). Causes of this shortened hash are therefore possibly a different specification, a bug, etc.

Comment: thanks Topaco, I've been also struggling truing to find an implementation for this.

Comment: @EduardoAEDUARDOFernandezDi - In any case, the short hash violates the format CISCO specifies with $8$: $8$ expects a salt followed by the associated PBKDF2 hash (separated with $), which the short hash does not satisfy. In contrast, the code I posted, as well as the linked code produce $8$ compliant hashes. So the problem is most likely with the CLI tool (improper configuration, buggy etc).

Answer (score 0):

The required command, enable algorithm-type sha256 secret thePassword, needs to be considered.  Without that, it can't be done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).